# Change white space background color

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change the background color of text within a div if it is a white space `&nbsp` only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Put it in a `span`  element so that the element isn't larger than the text and set the background-color of this element.

```
<div><span style="background-color:red;">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

Comment: This actually changed all text background but I suspect this is some CSS somewhere else. Either way I got the result, thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why wouldn’t it? What did you try? For example, the following works ok:

```
<div style="background-color: green">&nbsp;</div>
```

Background color can be set even if the element’s content is completely empty, `<div></div>`. Its height will be zero by default, so the background color has no effect, but if you set the `width` property to nonzero, you will see the background in the color set.